# Pythonic way of initialising class with infrequently variables optional arguments

Tags: python-3.x, class, decorator, instantiation, setter

## Background

I'm working on an `Element` class that is of the following charactirtics:

- Stores `bespoke_data` variable that varies across instances
- Stores `components` variable that *seldom* varies across instances. I.e. in majority of instances the content of components variable is constant; however, on odd occasions additional entries have to be added or removed
- Class offers some methods that usually utilise the data available within the `bespoke_data` and `components` variables.

### Problem

What approach should I take to provide end-users with convenient way of instantiating objects using that class. In the present implementation, if the end-user wishes to instantiate class using a different set of components they would have to provide a new list:

```py
e = Element(components=['G1', 'G2'], bespoke_data='Some text G1 and G2.')
```

The problem arrises that, in majority of cases the end-user would only need to add or remove a component. A potentially more user-friendly ways of initialising the class would be:

```py
e = Element(additional_components=['Z1', '2'], # Added to the default list
            superfluous_components=['E1'],     # Removed from the default list
            bespoke_data='Some text G1 and G2.')
```

In the example above the end-user can initiate class without the need to provide the full list of components. My questions is how to neatly reflect this in the class implementation

## Code

*Illustrative example with simple method and components.* The actual class contains much richer set of default components and more complex bespoke data element but the example below shows the gist of the problem.

```py
"""Example of the Element class
"""

from typing import List

class Element:
    """
    Element class representing elements objects
    consisting of components and bespoke parts
    """

    def __init__(self, bespoke_data: str, 
                 components: List =['E1', 'E2', 'E3', 'G1', 'G2']) -> None:
        """Initiate the Element class

        Args:
            components (dict): Components (seldom vary across instances)
            bespoke_data (str): Bespoke data (varies across instances)
        """
        self.bespoke_data = bespoke_data
        self.components = components

    @property
    def bespoke_data(self):
        return self._bespoke_data

    @bespoke_data.setter
    def bespoke_data(self, new_bespoke_data):
        if not isinstance(new_bespoke_data, str):
            raise TypeError("New bespoke data must be a string.")
        self._bespoke_data = new_bespoke_data
    
    @bespoke_data.deleter
    def bespoke_data(self):
        del self._bespoke_data

    @property
    def components(self):
        return self._components
    
    @components.setter
    def components(self, new_components):
        if not isinstance(new_components, List):
            raise TypeError("Components should be a list.")
        self._components = new_components

    def count_present_components(self):
        num_components = 0
        for component in self.components:
            num_components += self.bespoke_data.count(component)
        return num_components
```

Comment: well you just need to add those other arguments, probably as optional keyword arguments with a default to None, then write the logic to decide if the constructor was called correctly (i.e. it must either provide nothing, the whole component, or additional/superfluous) and then implement the logic

Comment: as an aside, do not use mutable default arguments.